# hide text from printing but keeping the space

Tags: html, css

We have in-house server which brings the records by php from mysql.

We have Dot matrix printer which we are using for printing on carbon less paper (2 copies:- one for official records,one for customer and one for gatekeeper).

We tried to print the content by display:none but it was removing that space from that Div.

Then we tried to print it with the white color font without display:none (we realized that print head reads everything), so it was printing the characters on the 2nd and 3rd copy.

So We want to know how can hide the text at the same time by keeping that much space blank.

Please tell how to do the same thing with border ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`visibility: hidden;` makes it invisible, but leaves the space.

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility)

Comment: Please tell me how can I do same thing with border ?

Comment: @dave Make a border the color of the background?

Comment: it'll not print on the first sheet, but printer header will read it and it'll print on the carbon sheet

Comment: @dave Set the border color to `transparent`, or use margins to match the missing border (e.g. if the border is 1px, add 1px to the margin)

Comment: Thanks Zirak, I'll try this one.

Answer (score 2):

you can keep the div with text in one div with height and width and give style `display:none` property to the div with text. this way the space will remain

Comment: This would mean that width and height must be fixed numbers. `visibility:hidden;` is much better for keeping space with the same size as its content.